# How to reinitialize Multiple Sticky Titles after showing/hiding items

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, sticky

I have created a sidebar with multiple sticky titles based off the code in this popular codepen example: http://codepen.io/chrissp26/pen/gBrdo

The titles that are sticky, are also clickable, and on click, I am showing/hiding items related to the title. While both the sticky titles and expanding/collapsing the related items, are functional, when I use them together I get undesired results. The following code is what is used to handle the sticky titles:

```
function stickyTitles(stickies) 
{
    this.load = function() 
    {
        stickies.each(function(){

            var thisSticky = jQuery(this).wrap('<div class="followWrap" />');
            thisSticky.parent().height(thisSticky.outerHeight());

            jQuery.data(thisSticky[0], 'pos', thisSticky.offset().top);
        });
    }

    this.scroll = function() 
    {
        stickies.each(function(i){              

            var thisSticky = jQuery(this),
            nextSticky = stickies.eq(i+1),
            prevSticky = stickies.eq(i-1),
            pos = jQuery.data(thisSticky[0], 'pos') - 70;

            if (pos <= jQuery('#container').scrollTop()) {
                thisSticky.addClass("fixed");

                if (nextSticky.length > 0 && thisSticky.offset().top >= jQuery.data(nextSticky[0], 'pos') - thisSticky.outerHeight()) {
                    thisSticky.addClass("absolute").css("top", jQuery.data(nextSticky[0], 'pos') - thisSticky.outerHeight());
                }
            } else {
                thisSticky.removeClass("fixed");

                if (prevSticky.length > 0 && jQuery('#container').scrollTop() <= jQuery.data(thisSticky[0], 'pos')  - prevSticky.outerHeight() + 200) {
                    prevSticky.removeClass("absolute").removeAttr("style");
                }
            }   
        });         
    }
}
```

I see the function is calculating the distance from the top, so when I collapse/expand the items, the position relative to the top changes. This is what causes the undesired user experience. I added the following code inside my click event, hoping the position from the top would be recalculated AFTER the items are collapsed/expanded:

```
var newStickies = new stickyTitles(jQuery(".followMeBar"));

newStickies.load();

jQuery('#container').on("scroll", function() {
    newStickies.scroll();
});
```

Unfortunately, the position does not seem to be recalculated, and the positions before expanding/collapsing are used instead.

I have created this JSFiddle that demonstrates my issue: http://jsfiddle.net/vo78hr4x/1/

Answer (score 0):

use the load function after adding new html contnent

```
   this.load = function() 
{
    stickies.each(function(){

        var thisSticky = jQuery(this).wrap('<div class="followWrap" />');
        thisSticky.parent().height(thisSticky.outerHeight());

        jQuery.data(thisSticky[0], 'pos', thisSticky.offset().top);
    });
}
```

Comment: here instead on stickies it would be stickies=jQuery(".followMeBar");